# Listing prices on single line and being grouped by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get four different pricing options on one single line grouped by the date.

I have two tables, one listing the item with its various descriptors and a second with the item's pricing history. The issue is that I have four different buy options with separate lines for each. Each item in the sale section lists the buy option then price for that particular day. What I'm trying to do is Group By the date and be able to see the price for all 4 options each day.

```
SELECT
s.date,
CASE WHEN s.code = 'Option 1' THEN s.price ELSE NULL END AS Option 1,
CASE WHEN s.code = 'Option 2' THEN s.price ELSE NULL END AS Option 2,
CASE WHEN s.code = 'Option 3' THEN s.price ELSE NULL END AS Option 3,
CASE WHEN s.code = 'Option 4' THEN s.price ELSE NULL END AS Option 4
FROM main_itempage i
JOIN main_sales s ON i.id = s.item_id
WHERE i.id = '[item's id]' AND s.territory_id = 'US' and date 
BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
GROUP BY date
```

While I want to see the four different prices on one line, all I'm getting is one line with only Option 1's price listed. The other three columns are only coming back as NULL. When I take out the grouping, it will give four separate lines for each day with only one column's price filled in. Any help, is appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT s.date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.code = 'Option 1' THEN s.price ELSE NULL END) AS Option 1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.code = 'Option 2' THEN s.price ELSE NULL END) AS Option 2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.code = 'Option 3' THEN s.price ELSE NULL END) AS Option 3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.code = 'Option 4' THEN s.price ELSE NULL END) AS Option 4
FROM main_itempage i JOIN
     main_sales s
     ON i.id = s.item_id
WHERE i.id = '[item''s id]' AND
      s.territory_id = 'US' and
      date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
GROUP BY date;
```